# exception error: no match of right hand side value 2

Tags: erlang

I has code that is looking for max palindrome, alias N = reverse(N). The code isn't complete yet. But help me please find out reason of exception.

```
find_palindrome(List1, List2, Increment, IfPalindrome) ->
  List_of_values = [X * Y || X <- List1, Y <- List2],
  find_palindrome(0, 1, List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome).

find_palindrome(Max, N, List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome) ->
  case IfPalindrome(lists:nth(N, List_of_values)) of
    true ->
      case Max < lists:nth(N, List_of_values) of
        true ->
          Max = lists:nth(N, List_of_values),
          find_palindrome(Max, Increment(N), List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome);
        false ->
          find_palindrome(Max, Increment(N), List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome)
      end;
    false ->
      find_palindrome(Max, Increment(N), List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome)
  end.


check_palindrome(N) ->
  (N) == (list_to_integer(lists:reverse(integer_to_list(N)))).

problem4() ->
  find_palindrome(lists:seq(100, 999), lists:seq(100, 999), fun(X) -> X = X + 1 end, fun check_palindrome/1).
```

I am constantly getting exception:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 2
     in function  euler4:'-problem4/0-fun-0-'/1 (euler4.erl, line 36)
     in call from euler4:find_palindrome/5 (euler4.erl, line 28)
```

Comment: This is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438041/409228 . Did you bother searching SO before asking your question? This question has already been answered here numerous times.

Comment: Before you can know that it is a duplicate of other questions about variable immutability, you first need to know that this is about variable immutability, and more importantly, know that such a thing exists.

This is a duplicate of the first link, but I can not see how it's a duplicate of the second one. And you kind of need to know the answer to the question before you can see that it's a duplicate.

Be nice.

Comment: This question is about a specific piece of code not working. The fact that the solution is similar to another question doesn't make it a duplicate. Many questions can be answered by the same or similar answer, but it's the fact why a particular answer answers a particular question that matters, not the answer on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in Erlang shell:

```
1> X = 1.
1
2> X = X + 1.
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 2
```

This is because in Erlang variables can only be assigned once. It's called [single assignment](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79358). Once a variable is bound to a value, that variable can't be be bound to any other value. The value stored in a variable can't change. You need to create a new variable. In this particular case you could write:

```
3> Y = X + 1.
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `=` is really a pattern matching operator, not assignment. The left-hand side can be any pattern, not just a variable. You can write e.g. `2 = 1 + 1` and this will successfully match, while `3 = 1 + 1` will give you `no match of right hand side value 2`. And bound variables can be used in the pattern for their values, e.g. `X = 2, X = 1 + 1` will succeed.

So in `Max = lists:nth(N, List_of_values)`, because `Max` is already bound (as the argument of the function), its value is used, and it ends up being `0 = lists:nth(1, List_of_values)` (with values from `find_palindrome(0, 1, List_of_values, Increment, IfPalindrome)` which will fail unless `List_of_values` starts with `0`.